# How to swap classes back and forth - jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

```
$('.chk-box').on('click',function(){
  $('.chk-box').removeClass('fa-square');
  $('.chk-box').addClass('fa-check-square', 'active');
});
```

I want it so if you click .chk-box while it's fa-square it adds fa-check-square and active but how do i make it so it removes fa-check-square and adds fa-square and active when you click fa-check-square

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you tell us what you have tried to get this working yourself? Can you show us the code (even if it's broken)? then we can help you make it work. How about pseudo code? if you're not sure where to begin - imagine you had a magic wand and could write any code you liked - what would you write? We can then help you to change the bits that don't actually exist into the ones that do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `toggleClass`:

```
$('.chk-box').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-square fa-check-square active');
});
```

If the class is already on the element it will remove it, and vice versa. Also, you should use `this` within the handler to only make the class changes affect the clicked element.

[API docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

Answer (score 1):

Can try another alternative way,

```
$('.chk-box').on('click',function(){
  var this=$(this);
  if(this.hasClass('fa-square')) {
    this.removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-square active');
  } else {
    this.removeClass('fa-check-square active').addClass('fa-square');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="fa-square"/>
```

jquery:

```
$('.chk-box').on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('fa-square fa-check-square active');
```

});`